# AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF) mySQL returning wrong answers

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, timestamp, average

Below is the code I am using to calculate the average session duration for users.

```
SELECT 
    tbl.create_Date
   ,HourOfDay
   ,HourOfDay_AMPM

   ,AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, tbl.minDt, tbl.maxDt))/60 AS Duration_mins

  FROM (SELECT 
           i.session_id,
           i.createDate,
           DATE(CONVERT_TZ(i.createDate, '+00:00', '-04:00')) as create_Date,
           HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(i.createDate, '+00:00', '-04:00')) as HourOfDay,
           DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(i.createDate,'+00:00','-04:00'), '%l%p') as HourOfDay_AMPM,
           min(i.createDate) minDt,
           max(i.createDate) maxDt,
           (max(i.createDate) - min(i.createDate) )/60 as Duration
      FROM impressions i 

     WHERE i.createDate >= current_date
     AND HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(i.createDate, '+00:00', '-04:00')) >=9
     AND HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(i.createDate, '+00:00', '-04:00')) < 22
     AND i.session_Id <> ''


     GROUP BY i.session_id
     HAVING Duration > 0
     ORDER BY i.createDate, i.session_id

        ) as tbl
 GROUP BY  tbl.create_DATE, tbl.HourOfDay

 ORDER by tbl.create_Date
```

Note, the time zone in the database is in UTC and I needed to display the results in EST, which is why I used the convert_TZ commands.

**Problem**: I ran the **inner** query and pasted the raw data into Excel, generated a pivot table and got the following results

```
Hour    Avg_duration_mins
9AM     14.43
10AM    59.17
11AM    24.55
12PM    12.69
2PM     1.27
```

**However**, running the **whole** query as is gives me the following results

```
 Hour    Avg_duration_mins
 9AM    6.98
10AM    18.78
11AM    9.40
12PM    7.49
 2PM    1.21
```

Having manually checked, the excel results are accurate and makes sense. Why is the SQL going crazy? I have a feeling that the issue lies with the `AVG` function and the aggregation of `max` and `min`.

Update: for the table impressions there can be multiple entries of the same `session_id`

```
session_id     |   createDate     |    actions     |
   023awv        2014-10-09 12:02     some action
   023awv        2014-10-09 12:12     some action
   023awv        2014-10-09 12:22     some action
   023awv        2014-10-09 12:32     some action
   011awv        2014-10-09 12:42     some action
   023awv        2014-10-09 12:42     some action
   023awv        2014-10-09 12:52     some action
   023awv        2014-10-09 12:53     some action
   052brw        2014-10-09 13:02     some action
   023awv        2014-10-09 13:05     some action
   023awv        2014-10-09 13:06     some action
   023awv        2014-10-09 13:08     some action
   023awv        2014-10-09 13:12     some action
```

I want to get the average duration per session at an hourly/daily basis.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The session is 70 minutes long. Should it be accounted to the 12:00 bucket or the 13:00 bucket? The way you have the query this is an essentially random choice.

Comment: This is an excellent point and I am having issues with that as well. I thought that it will select the start time of the session and bucket it that slot.

Comment: @Laurence: if you can help me start of a fresh slate, I will be grateful. I feel like I have confused myself enough. If you were to do this, how would you have done? I feel like the `AVG` function is not calculating what I think it should. Running the inner query, I am getting the correct number of rows per hour slot, and I felt that grouping it by the HOUR will enable the average to be taken at that hourly level. Was I wrong?

Comment: Just ran the queries as suggested; I am still getting the same incorrect results.

Comment: When you do the Excel calculation, are you using the value from `(max(i.createDate) - min(i.createDate) )/60)`? This isn't the duration in minutes. You'd need to use timestampdiff to get that.

Comment: No. I am using the `Duration` field that is there in the original code. I tried to take it out and run it as you wrote it; the results from BOTH queries are the same; both are incorrect.

To clarify, I have the duration in minutes calculated from the inner query. I pasted it, used a pivot table, took an average by the hour and the results were different with the excel ones being correct (verified by manual check)

Comment: Can you post up the results you get for the inner query, the excel calculations and the outer query for the test data set. (ignoring the `>= current_date bit`)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `(max(i.createDate) - min(i.createDate) )/60 as Duration` as a number of minutes in the Excel calculation, then this is wrong. Subtracting dates provides some kind of interval representation:

```
select timestamp('2014-10-09 14:12') - timestamp('2014-10-09 13:04');

> 10800
```

This is "1 hour 8 minutes" not 4080 seconds.

Your inner query has a group by, but also includes non-aggregated non-grouped columns. In simple terms:

```
select
    session_id,
    createDate -- this isn't grouped or aggregated
from
    impressions i
group by
    session_id
```

Most databases won't let you do this. MySQL will, it will return the first `createDate`  it happens upon for each `session_id`. So your inner query produces non-stable results. The query plan for running it separately is probably different to the query plan for running the queries together. So it ends up returning different values in each case.

Say the impressions table contained the following two rows:

```
session_id | createDate
--------------------------------
         1 | 2014-10-09 13:30:00
         1 | 2014-10-09 15:30:00
```

What should the inner query return? What should the outer query return?

One way to fix the problem is to bucket your results based on the minimum date:

```
select
    tbl.Create_Date,
    tbl.HourOfDay,
    tbl.HourOfDay_AMPM,
    avg(timestampdiff(second, tbl.minDt, tbl.maxDt))/60 as Duration_mins
from (
    select
       i.session_id,
       date(convert_tz(min(i.createDate), '+00:00', '-04:00')) as create_Date,
       hour(convert_tz(min(i.createDate), '+00:00', '-04:00')) as HourOfDay,
       date_format(convert_tz(min(i.createDate), '+00:00', '-04:00'), '%l%p') as HourOfDay_AMPM,
       min(i.createDate) minDt,
       max(i.createDate) maxDt,
       (max(i.createDate) - min(i.createDate) )/60 as Duration
    from
        impressions i 
    where
        i.createDate >= current_date and
        hour(convert_tz(i.createDate, '+00:00', '-04:00')) >=9 and
        hour(convert_tz(i.createDate, '+00:00', '-04:00')) < 22 and
        i.session_Id <> ''
    group by
        i.session_id
    having
        Duration > 0
    ) as tbl
group by
    tbl.Create_Date,
    tbl.HourOfDay,
    tbl.HourOfDay_AMPM
order by
    tbl.create_Date,
    tbl.HourOfDay
```

Here I've basically replaced every non-aggregated occurrence of i.CreateDate in the inner query with min(i.CreatDate). This makes the inner query well defined. I.e. there is only one result set that it could return.

From reading the MySQL manual, it's very hard to work out what putting an order in an inner query will do in this situation. The manual says an outer order will take precedence over an inner order.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I am curious if you can propose a fix. I am a newbie to this and am still confused by your explanation. If you were to go in an edit the code, how would you do it?

Comment: @eager_learner313 I've put a question at the end of my answer for discussion.

Comment: The inner query returns the same results every time. It's the outer one that returns different results.

The inner query should produce the following 
`session_id | minDt | maxDt`
`1 | 2014-10-09 13:30:00 | 2014-10-09 15:30:00`

Comment: @eager_learner313 The inner query has more than three columns, what should `i.createDate` return, for example?

Comment: Let me provide an example of the sample table. Will that help?

Comment: RE: i.createDate; it should just append the `datetime` value with each session. If I take it out, the results are still incorrect.

Comment: is there a reason you took out the line `(max(i.createDate) - min(i.createDate) )/60 as Duration` from the inner query? `Duration` is there in the `HAVING` statement. Just curious.